# how to change eclipse's editor to show or edit code in multiple columns?

Tags: eclipse, editor

My laptop and desktop monitors are wider than they are tall. When I'm looking at code, from half to 2/3 of the screen is empty with no code. This is silly.

I'd like to take a look at how to extend eclipse's editor to show data in multiple columns.

If anyone has any idea regarding what api I should lookup or any other resources, please point them out.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if one viewer can display code in multiple columns, but you can [split a view for the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198822/eclipse-same-java-file-in-split-view) (`Window -> New editor`).

That way, you can see more of your code, each tab using that horizontal space you have so much on your screen.

For different files, you can put different editor side-to-side:

[image: drag]

That will give:

[image: sidetoside]

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't what I'm looking for. I know eclipse doesn't have a way of showing code in multiple columns. I thought I might look at relevant APIs to hack an editor which does do so. I've never used eclipse API and their docs don't make it very clear.

Comment: @Shahbaz Eclipse does have a way of showing code (even for a same file) in multiple "column", as long as you accept an editor as an acceptable "column".

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) there is the "Window/Editor/Toggle split editor vertical" menu option which does exactly what you need. There is also Toggle split editor horizontal option there.