# How do I sync split editor panes in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm coming back to Eclipse after using IntelliJ or whatever for a while, and the first thing I'm trying to do is making me crazy.

I want two editor views of the same file ("Splitting an editor" in the Eclipse documentation); and when I make a change in one of those editors, I want it to show up in the other!  (Like, you know, any other editor with a "split pane" feature.  I've only tried this in a Markdown editor and a Bash editor, so I suppose my problem could be with those plugins.  This is using Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12.0).)

All I see in the [Eclipse documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tips/platform_tips.html) is this:

> **Splitting an editor**
>
> To view or edit multiple sections of an editor at once, you can split / unsplit the currently active editor via:
>
> ```
>  Window > Editor > Toggle Split Editor (Horizontal)
>  Window > Editor > Toggle Split Editor (Vertical)
> ```
>
> Or just use one of the key bindings:
>
> ```
>  Ctrl+_ to split horizontally
>  Ctrl+{ to split vertically
> ```
>
> You can also open a second editor instance via Window > Editor > Clone.

Both `Window > Editor > Toggle Split Editor` and `Window > Editor > Clone` give me the same result: two views of the same file which aren't in sync, and which seem to be brain-damaged.  If I type or cut/paste in one editor, the changes don't show up in the other; if I Ctrl-S in the other, the first is still marked as modified; Ctrl-S in the first (or trying to save when closing) gives an error, saying the contents have changed on disk.  (No kidding!  *You changed them!!)*

[This answer from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2198846/7387167) sounds like there's some drag-tabs-until-you-see-an-arrow step needed to keep the two panes in sync, but I don't think that's current, and I haven't been able to drag tabs around in a way which makes an arrow show up.

This is making me so crazy, I'm thinking about editing this definitely-non-Android-stuff in Android Studio, just because I know it will do the basic editing tasks I want to do.

Comment: This works fine with the Java editor and the plain text editor, which suggests it is those specific plug-ins

Comment: Aww, man, you're right!  (Originally I was having the problem in a Markdown file; I only tried it to reproduce it in one of the project's bash scripts to confirm that it wasn't just the plugin.  I didn't seriously think it would be *both* of the plugins I cared about!)

If you want to post that again as an answer ("original poster is a bozo" or something), I will accept it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are looking to compare both files.
Click and select the two files you want in split screen. Right click and select compare > Each Other [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M5rU.png)